# how to manage Cloud SQL connection pool on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I need to manage Cloud SQL max_connections, to prevent too many connecitons error.
So how can I manage connections on Cloud Run?

Comment: Support for limiting max instances would be supported soon. Until then you can’t really throttle total connections to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run now support max instances as a way to limit the number of upstream Cloud SQL connections. This can be set at deploy time or on an existing service:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE --max-instances MAX-VALUE
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE --max-instances MAX-VALUE
```

`MAX-VALUE` is any integer value from 1 to 1000. Using `default` will clear any maximum instance setting.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances